# Amazon EC2 automatic reboot and script running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, restart

I'm trying to get a amazon ec2 instance to automatically reboot each 2 hours, and after run a shell (.sh) script on startup. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For rebooting after 2 hours, if it is Ubuntu (or Debian based distro) just put on root's cron (by entering sudo crontab -e):

```
* */2 * * * /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very curious as to why you need to reboot every 2 hours... I hope this is not a production server... but you could run a cronjob to do the rebooting, what type of instance do you have, is it linux or windows?

I have a centos instance and I have modified **/etc/rc.d/rc.local** to run a script after booting up but then again you could easily run a script via cronjob to check whether something is running or not...

I guess we need more information from you as to what you are trying to do and what type of instance you have.